# assembly clean screen - Graphic mode

Tags: assembly, graphics, mouse

I guys !! maybe some of you saw my question - and again about the game..
and finally a understand what and how to do (thank for all the friends who helped me).. but i got a little problem.

i need to print a character, than ckean the screen and print the character in other place. i have a proc which clean the screen but it doesn't work really well and Leaving little "residue" of the character on the screen.
maybe its because the mouse (i put on the character).

Im adding my proc - please check if there is a problem - also if you have a better proc i will glad to see.

Thank you all !!

```
proc ClearScreen
push ax
push es
push di
push cx
mov ax,screen_RAM_graphics
mov es,ax          ; es:di - video memory
xor di,di
mov cx,320*200/2
mov al,0          ; color
mov ah,0             ; color
rep stosw            ; mov es:[di],ax     add di,2
pop cx
pop di
pop es
pop ax
ret
```

endp ClearScreen

Comment: You might want to add *which* graphics mode this is supposed to be. The memory addressing, as well as other things, vary widely.

Comment: Which graphics mode, which operating system (if any), etc.

Comment: This would work in 13h PC BIOS/DOS mode 320x200 with 256 colours. And your clear screen is perfect. If you got any artefacts, it's because you did draw something after the screen was already clear (or you have bug in some custom interrupt handler which will destroy register value half-way into the clearing). (btw, you can set `ah:al = 0:0` by single `xor ax,ax`, no need for two `mov r8,imm8` instructions).